# JSON - $.GETJSON seems keep requesting

Tags: jquery, append, each, appendto, getjson

Not sure if I am doing something wrong.
But when I run the following script, it seems to load the same information twice.

When it should only show the information once.
I am wondering if I have missed something?

```
    $.getJSON('system/classes/core.php?task=listmyleads&userid='+userid, function(data) {

      $.each(data,function(i,myinfo){
            $("tbody").append('<tr>'+
'           <td id="row" class="small"><input id="'+myinfo.customer_id+'" type="checkbox"></td>'+
'           <td>'+myinfo.CreatedTime+'</td>'+
'           <td>'+myinfo.Company+'</td>'+
'           <td class="center">'+myinfo.FirstName+' '+myinfo.LastName+'</td>'+
'           <td class="center">'+myinfo.Phone+'</td>'+
'           <td class="center bigger">'+myinfo.Email+'</td>'+
'           <td class="center">'+myinfo.stafffirstname+' '+myinfo.stafflastname+'</td>'+
'           <td class="center last">A</td>'+
'       </tr>');
      });

    });
```

Here is a link to the data - http://incard.com.au/telesales/system/classes/core.php?task=listmyleads&userid=1

Comment: I have noticed that when I do an alert(i) its going from 0 to 1 each time its ran

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't see anything that would cause it to run twice.  Check to make sure that the $.getJSON function isn't being called multiple times, possibly by attaching an event to some element multiple times.

The other possibility is more than one JSON object being returned from your request.  Use firebug to check what the actual data coming down the wire is.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `data` contains more than one record - are you echoing it twice in PHP?

Comment: no i am not here is the link to the data, am using print http://incard.com.au/telesales/system/classes/core.php?task=listmyleads&userid=1

Answer (score -1):

The JSON you're serving isn't actually valid JSON (you can check it by pasting it in to [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) or [jslint](http://jslint.com)). Try removing the `(` and `)` at the beginning and end of the string, respectively.